# How to install cdm?

Tags: software-installation

I would like to replace the default login manager that comes with Ubuntu with [cdm](https://github.com/ghost1227/cdm/)  . How can I do that and what problems can I expect?

Comment: Try out the steps and let us know if you face any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the zip file from the [link](https://github.com/ghost1227/cdm/zipball/master)

```
unzip ghost1227-cdm-04d35a5.zip
cd ghost1227-cdm-04d35a5/

sudo ./install.sh
```

use `sudo` since cdm tries to copy the contents to `/etc` and `/usr/bin`

As suggested in readme to add cdm to startup do the following.

> To autostart cdm when you log in your account, copy the content of
>   /usr/share/doc/cdm/profile.sh to the tail of your shell profile
>   (~/.profile, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

as i have seen , it contains a install.sh file .so by doing this in terminal you can install it .

extract that and cd to that from terminal .then 
do as

```
chmod +x install.sh
./install.sh
```

Comment: I just wan to make sure that everything will go fine and I won't see a black screen or an error message on the next boot. Has someone tried installing cdm in practice?